# Add Browse button in dynamically created view - Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, webforms, entity-framework-4, scaffolding

In my model I want to add a string property that will save the url/path of an image. For that I need to add "`Browse`" button next to a `textbox` for the user to select file & also a `Image` to display the selected image.

How can I save this image somewhere else and not in the DB - as that will increase the size of DB and save time for transferring image from `byte[]` to file & vice-versa ? Like this, through out the project, I will have many images to upload & show. Right now I am on local DB, Is this possible to achieve, if so, how?

The view file where I want to add browse & Image is like this:

```
<asp:DynamicControl Mode="Insert" DataField="PANNumber" runat="server" />
```

it's inside `<InsertItemTemplate> <fieldset> & <Validate-Summary>`

The view is created by scaffolding.

Comment: So you want to save the images in physical path and also display the image as preview?

Comment: Yes, that's what I had thought of. But, if I don't show path, then in Model how to go with it ?? I can Exclude the text box of that field. Your point makes sense - y to show the path. But how to show button and Image as preview in the View.